# Spring, How to set error message from custom constraint validator at runtime

Tags: spring, spring-boot, kotlin

I have this constraint for validating dhcp host addresses.

```
annotation class DHCPAddressConstraint(
  val message: String = "Invalid dhcp address.",
  val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
  val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = [],
  val cidrField: String = "",
  val addressRangeField: String = ""
)

class DHCPAddressValidator: ConstraintValidator<DHCPAd, Any> {
  override fun isValid(obj: Any, context: ConstraintValidatorContext): Boolean {
    val cidr = ReflectionUtils.get(obj, cidrField)
    val addressRange = ReflectionUtils.get(obj, addressRangeField)
    return isValidCIDR(cidr) && isValidAdressRange(cidr, addressRange)
  }
}
```

So if something is invalid it would return just "Invalid dhcp address.". I want to set the error message to be more specific so why is it invalid. For example the dhcp address range may not be in the CIDR range or the user enters reserved IP address and so on. I expect to have error message like this "Invalid dhcp address due to ${reason}". how can I set the constraint error message at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

you could take help of @ControllerAdvice & @ExceptionHandler

Please look at the example code below

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionController {

    @ExceptionHandler(value = PageNotFoundApiException.class)
    public ResponseEntity<Object> pageNotFoundApiException(PageNotFoundApiException exception){
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Page Not Found 404", HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    }
}
```

You can also take a reference over this [documentation](https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring)

I hope, it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Using the passed, `ConstraintValidatorContext` object it is possible to either add additional error messages or completely disable the default error message generation and solely define custom error messages.

```
context.disableDefaultConstraintViolation();    
context.buildConstraintViolationWithTemplate("Specific error message....").addConstraintViolation();
```

6.1.2.1. The ConstraintValidatorContext - [Documentation](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator-backup/5.2/reference/en-US/html/validator-customconstraints.html)